# How can I reverse this simple jQuery fadeIn effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse, fadein

So, this script creates an easing swift effect when you click on the button (id="enter") and what I want is that when you click it once again it will reverse the effect and go back to the beginning. Also, another solution can be with 2 buttons so one can do the first part and the other can reverse the action.
Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#enter').click(function() {
    $('#slide2').fadeIn(1000, 'linear', function(){
        $('#slide3').fadeIn(1000, 'linear');
    });
});
```

There are three images: slide1, slide2 and slide3. I actually found this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6hUr/1/ and this is how it should look but I only need reverse now.

Comment: You could just handle it in CSS by toggling a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have more than one slide so fadeToggle can not give you exact reverse 
Fine below code that can give you exact reverse of fadeIn effect

```js
var forward = true;
$('#enter').click(function() {
  if(forward == true){
    $('#slide2').fadeIn(1000, 'linear', function(){
      $('#slide3').fadeIn(1000, 'linear');
    });
    forward = false;
  }else{
    $('#slide3').fadeOut(1000, 'linear', function(){
      $('#slide2').fadeOut(1000, 'linear');
    });
    forward = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
    <li id="slide1" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/drawing.jpg">
    </li>
    <li id="slide2" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-day-time.jpg">
    </li>
    <li id="slide3" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-night-time.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>

<button id="enter" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: snippet's broken

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#enter').click(function() {
    $('#slide2').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear', function(){
        $('#slide3').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear');
    });
});
```

Just Toggle your fade effect.

Comment: I tried it in JSFiddle and it works but it doesn't work in Wordpress. Strange.

Comment: @senn205 is it giving any error on your developer console?

Comment: I checked it and there aren't any errors. And also I changed $ to jQuery but it still didn't work. It only executes first part and the reverse is not working.

Comment: @senn205 Check that button is clickable, i mean not overlapped by any other element (slides). And btw, this is not the effect you are lloking for because on second click, the first div to fade out isn't the slide3 but still slide2

Comment: @A.Wolff I will check it and yes I know that but first I need to get it work in the Wordpress and then solve that problem. Do you know how the code should look? But I'll only use 2 photos, not three.

Comment: @senn205 You should use CSS transition imho, check my answer. Now regarding not working in wordpress, myabe you didn't clear browser cache. Now i'm not a wordpress dev so...

Comment: Okay, will try your method.

Comment: Any luck @senn205 ?

Comment: Hey @gschambial I had luck with your method but when I click the button it processes the script and then returns it to the beginning. So you click it and as it should fade the images and stop, it automatically starts the reverse. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @senn205  If you have noticed ,This is not exact reverse effect , When you click button second time slide2 is displayed first , slide 3 is displayed  second and slide 1 is displayed third. See my answer that will give you exact reverse effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way you can do that with fadIn,fadeOut and fadeToogle for reverse effect change slide order in jquery see below code. For identify fade effect we are manage data-fade attribute in button.

```js
$('#enter').click(function() {
  var fade_type = $(this).data('fade');

  if (fade_type == "in") {
    $('#slide2').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear', function() {
      $('#slide3').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear');
    });
    $(this).data('fade', 'out');
  } else {
    $('#slide3').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear', function() {
      $('#slide2').fadeToggle(1000, 'linear');
    });
    $(this).data('fade', 'in');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li id="slide1" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/drawing.jpg">
  </li>
  <li id="slide2" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-day-time.jpg">
  </li>
  <li id="slide3" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: none; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-night-time.jpg">

  </li>
</ul>

<button id="enter" type="button" data-fade="in">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it using CSS transition and in jQuery, you just toggle a class:

### -jsFiddle-

```js
$('#enter').click(function() {
  $('#slide2, #slide3').toggleClass('fadeIn');
});
```

```css
#enter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
#slide2, #slide3 {
  opacity: 0;  
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

#slide2.fadeIn, #slide3.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
}
#slide2:not(.fadeIn), #slide3.fadeIn
{
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li id="slide1" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; display: list-item; ">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/drawing.jpg">
  </li>
  <li id="slide2" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%;">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-day-time.jpg">
  </li>
  <li id="slide3" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%;">
    <img alt="Panoramic view from the window of one of the penthouses" src="http://tritonpenthouses.uwpistol.net/images/bg/cgi-night-time.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="enter" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```